# javascript in select in selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I'm trying set item in select using javascript (in variable I have date)

Here is how I'm trying set this item

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>Recent-Year</td>
    <td>value=javascript{d=new Date();d.getYear()}</td>
</tr>
```

I get:

```
[error] Option with value 'javascript{d=new Date();d.getYear()}' not found
```

of cource when I'm trying by this:

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>Recent-Year</td>
    <td>value=2011</td>
</tr>
```

it works.

What I must to change in this code to set this item?

**EDIT**

I don't want to split this command into few commands, because in another testcase I have stored variable birthday

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Date('1966,09,16')</td>
    <td>dateOfBirth</td>
</tr>
```

and I have 3 selects : Birth-Day, Birth-Month and Birth-Yearand I don't want to create 3 variables.

I want to set items in select like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td>select</td>
        <td>Birth-Year</td>
        <td>value =${dateOfBirth.getFullYear()}</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

Store the JavaScript evaluation first (using `storeEval`) and then use this variable as your option value:

```
<tr>
  <td>storeEval</td>
  <td>new Date().getYear()</td>
  <td>varYear</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>Recent-Year</td>
    <td>value=${varYear}</td>
</tr>
```

That should work

---

**Update**: In response to your edit: you can't use the `value=` with JavaScript but you can use the `storedVars` variable available in the JavaScript environment to create all the variables you need. For example, `storedVars['myVar']` can be accessed directly through Selenium as `${myVar}`. Below, I use `verifyEval` to run some JavaScript that will create all the variables I need.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Date()</td>
    <td>myDate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyEval</td>
    <td>var date=storedVars['myDate']; storedVars['day']=date.getDate(); storedVars['month']=date.getMonth(); storedVars['year']=date.getFullYear();</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can select the options based on:

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>Birth-Day</td>
    <td>value=${day}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>Birth-Month</td>
    <td>value=${month}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>Birth-Year</td>
    <td>value=${year}</td>
</tr>
```

I know it's not the ideal solution, but it does help a bit since you can't do `value=javascript{...}` (not that I know of anyway but if anyone else knows otherwise then please say).

Comment: yes, that works and thanks for that, but It's not I want, because in another testcase I have stored variable birthday (new Date('1974,09,16')) and I have 3 selects : dayOfBirth, monthOfBirth and yearOfBirth and I don't want to create 3 variables. I want to set items in select eg value =${dateOfBirth.getFullYear()}

Comment: @user278618 I've updated my answer. Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to do what you're looking for but I've provided a solution that at least minimises the amount you need to do.

Comment: @Downvoter - any reason why you downvoted? If there's anything you suggest then please help by leaving a comment.

Comment: Yours solution is what I did before in my code. I had hope that there is other simpler solution.